# Como crear fichero .env en windows

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Intento crear un archivo .env en windows y me dice que debo escribir un nombre para el archivo, cuando en realidad solo necesito el archivo con su tipo de extensión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias usar un editor de texto para crearlo y ejecutar este editor como administrador.

Comment: simple, hacelo desde un editor de texto, estoy seguro que no tendras problemas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crea el archivo .env pero termínalo con un punto adicional de esta forma `.env.`.

Al crear el archivo `.env.` automáticamente Windows crea un `.env` válido, puedes comprobarlo

Comment: ese no es el mismo archivo que quiere OP

Comment: al crear el archivo .env. automáticamente windows crea un .env válido, puedes comprobar :)

Comment: Si señor!!! Que buen descubrimiento. Aclara que hay que tener prendida ver la extension de archivos. ;)

Comment: Lo que son los hackers. Haha

*Sarcasmo

Answer (score 1):

Crea un bloc de notas y ábrelo

**Archivo > Guardar como...**

Ahora en la parte de Tipo, selecciona **Todos los archivos ( * . * )** y en el nombre de fichero pones **.env**, seleccionas la ubicación donde quieras guardarlo y listo.

Comment: Gracias, funciana.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus consejos, lo solucione con powershell
"ni .env"

Es que de la manera tradicional no me funciona, y antes si lo hacia.

Answer (score -2):

presiona `tecla windows` + `R`

escribe `cmd`

```
cd lacarpetadondecrearelarchivo
copy nul .env
```

opcionalmente para abrir el archivo para editar:

```
start notepad .env
```

Comment: Funciona. gracias